# Looking for a force resistor, but I just want it to act like a switch

Tags: switches

I can not for the life of me find something that is a force resistor, so it's flexible, but it acts like a switch.  I could also take just something that recognizes if a baby is sitting in a seat.  I just need something sensitive enough to sense a baby, is flexible, and just asks like a switch.

Comment: No force transducer is going "act like a switch". You're going to have to have some kind of signal conditioning.

Comment: Then do you have any other ideas?  I just need a flexible switch.  Sort of like a seat pad for elderly people that sounds an alarm, but I can't have the alarm.  Thanks!

Comment: It might not be sensitive enough for a baby, but most modern UK (and I assume European) cars have a sensor in the passenger seat to help warn the driver that the passenger hasn't fastened their seat belt. I'm not at all sure, but it might also disable or enable the passenger-side airbag. The point is, they must be a mass-produced item, likely affordable and easy to obtain.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you used to be able to. The [appnotes](http://www.rapidonline.com/pdf/06-1298e.pdf) for [QTC sensor pills](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_tunnelling_composite) from [Peratech ltd](http://www.peratech.com/) did suggest their use as (low current, 100mA or less) switches, since their resistance varied by about 7 orders of magnitude. They used to be available from [Maplin](http://www.maplin.co.uk/) (part N18BU) but apparently no more, except as part of their [Smart Materials kit](http://www.maplin.co.uk/p/mindsets-smart-materials-demo-box-a24rq) and a few other suppliers have [remaining stocks](http://www.rapidonline.com/design-technology/qtc-pills-each-06-1298).

Unfortunately they seem to have been EOLed so future supply may be difficult.

From the [Peratech FAQ](http://www.peratech.com/faq.html) :

> I have a custom requirement, what do I do?
> Please use the Contact form to get in touch with us. We will review your requirements and advise the most appropriate next steps.
>
> What happened to Elastomeric QTC and QTC Pills?
> These are both legacy products no longer supported by Peratech.
>
> Where can I find a data sheet for your standard products?
> There are downloads available with each product in the Standard Products section.

So it may be worth looking at their newer standard products or contacting them for more information on custom products.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like a "pressure pad" that closes a circuit when pressure is applied. Do a Google search for pressure pad and you will find many types and sizes.

Comment: I've done that and it brings up large floor mats that have alarms, and mats for like relieving stress on your feet.  I'm really at a loss for this, it's for a science project.